# Violate Core Data’s threading contractEXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1f0ad1c8c)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am facing one exception when uploading a task. I am starting the process on the background and fetch core data records I do not know how can I violated Core Data’s concurrency model. Please check the below code.

```
//Call methods in background
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        let onsourceNetwork = OnsourceNetworkUtility(withServiceRequestId: resources.value(forKey: "ServiceRequestId") as! String, inspectorId: resources.value(forKey: "InspectorId") as! String)
        onsourceNetwork?.delegate = self
        onsourceNetwork?.uploadResources()
    }
```

Got exception in this method.

```
//Fetch data from the core data
func fetchResourcesToBeUploaded(serviceRequestId: String, inspectorId: String) -> [ResourceMO] {
        let currentMOC = self.getCurrentContext()
        //upload status whether all chunks has been uploaded for a resource or not
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Resource")
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(serviceRequestId = %@ AND inspectorId = %@ AND uploadStatus = %@ OR uploadStatus = %@)", serviceRequestId, inspectorId, UploadStatus.Started.rawValue, UploadStatus.InProgress.rawValue)
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
        var resources = [ResourceMO]()
        do {
            resources = try currentMOC.fetch(request) as! [ResourceMO]// Core Data Violate here
        } catch {

            //print("Failed")
        }
        return resources;
    }
```

Please check image below for more details.
[image] 
[image]

Here is the get contextCode:

```
func getCurrentContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext {
        var curMOC:NSManagedObjectContext? = self.managedObjectContext
        let thisThread:Thread = Thread.current
        if thisThread == Thread.main {
            if curMOC != nil {
                return curMOC!
            }
            let coordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
            if coordinator != nil {
                curMOC = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
                curMOC?.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            }
            return curMOC!
        }
        // if this is some other thread....
        // Get the current context from the same thread..
        var threadManagedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext? = thisThread.threadDictionary.object(forKey:"ManagedObjectContext_Key") as? NSManagedObjectContext;
        // Return separate MOC for each new thread
        if threadManagedObjectContext != nil {
            return threadManagedObjectContext!;
        }

        let coordinator:NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
        if coordinator != nil {
            threadManagedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.privateQueueConcurrencyType)
            threadManagedObjectContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
            threadManagedObjectContext?.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
            threadManagedObjectContext?.undoManager = nil
            threadManagedObjectContext?.parent = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.mainQueueConcurrencyType)
            thisThread.threadDictionary.setObject(threadManagedObjectContext!, forKey: "ManagedObjectContext_Key" as NSCopying)
            assert((threadManagedObjectContext != nil))
        }
        return threadManagedObjectContext!;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using background thread?

Comment: For upload Images, video data into the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge amount of data that you want to insert or update in the core data then you should use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` for `your managed object context`. There are two types of concurrency in core data: `1) NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` and `2) NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`.

So, When you come to deal with large amount of data then you should use `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and there is no need for a separate background thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I set `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` type already. :)

Comment: Hey, please check here my code snippet. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4v8sixhi0khbkf/CoreDataController.swift?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

What's missing here is how did you create the self.currentContext managedObjectContext and is any other part of your code using the same context?

Did you created it with .viewContext or .newBackgroundContext?

I believe for your purpose you want .newBackgroundContext.

For your view you should have something like
        self.managedObjectContext = (NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

for the background queue it should be created like
        self.backgroundManagedObjectContext = (NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate).PersistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()

Comment: Thanks for the answer, let me try it.

Comment: You should have two NSManagedContext. One for the view and one for the background queue.

Comment: Hey, Please check here my code snippet. https://www.dropbox.com/s/p4v8sixhi0khbkf/CoreDataController.swift?dl=0

Comment: I looked at your Dropbox code. It's a singleton CoreDataController that I didn't see being used in your code. If you're just uploading images and video to a server you really don't need a Core Data background context.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `fetchResourcesToBeUploaded` from a different thread than `DispatachQueue.global`. Make sure you're fetching and using the resources on the same thread, for example by wrapping your whole upload logic in the `DispatchQueue.global` block:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  let resources = // call fetchResourcesToBeUploaded
  // other code
  let onsourceNetwork = OnsourceNetworkUtility(withServiceRequestId: resources.value(forKey: "ServiceRequestId") as! String, inspectorId: resources.value(forKey: "InspectorId") as! String)
  onsourceNetwork?.delegate = self
  onsourceNetwork?.uploadResources()
}
```

You need to make sure that you always fetch **and** use objects on the same thread. Fetching objects on one thread and then passing them to another is a multithreading violation:

```
let resources = // call fetchResourcesToBeUploaded

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
  // use resources
}
```

The above is an example of such a violation because the resources are fetched on some queue and then passed to global.